# Finding Best matches for a String value - Oracle/Java

Tags: java, string, oracle

Following up on my previous post [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054504/find-matching-records-with-least-characters-from-pattern-oracle-java), the other challenge we are now facing is find the best match for an Address field `[ADDR_LINE_1, ADDR_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP]`.

We want to return all the records in the database that would be a possible match to an incoming Address record[from the file]. The scenario is:

Following are 2 records in the database;

```
ADDR_LINE_1,        ADDR_LINE_2       , CITY       , STATE, ZIP
001 Chestnut Avenue, Apt 100          , Indiana     , IN  , 9999
Apt 100            , 001 Chestnut Ave., Indianapolis, IN  , 9999
```

For an incoming record, as follows

```
ADDR_LINE_1,        ADDR_LINE_2, CITY        , STATE, ZIP
1 Chestnut Avenue,   Apt 100   , Indiana     , IN   , 9999
```

I want to detect the record as an existing record and list the both of the above possible matches.

[Note:] The order of the database entries are interchanged, but still should be listed as a possible match.

Can anyone please provide suggestions as to how I can go about it?

Comment: First stage - define "possible match", to the point where there's no handwaving, and it's strongly defined whether a given record is a possible match or not.  Second stage - implement this boolean function (which should now be easy).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, here is what I can think of so far: I can at least filter out the records initially based on some "constant" values such as City, State, Zipcode. This would probably help me narrow down. Then for the String tokens in the Address Line 1 and Address Line 2, I can concatenate and find if at least 1/2 the tokens match i.e. concatenate "001 Chestnut Avenue" and "Apt 100" and compare with the incoming record "1 Chestnut Avenue Apt 100" and find at leat 3 of the 5 string tokens match. This makes the entire record a possible match.

Comment: I am a bit concerned though about the performance

Comment: Companies make a very fine living from selling data cleansing software to do this complicated sort of matching.   I think you are being very ambitious to want to solve it with regex alone.

Comment: @APC: Well, that is not currently what the company I am working for would look into :-) .. However, can you provide some references as well for these softwares?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to use the [UTL_MATCH package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm) to generate a similarity score and then fiddle with what threshold score seems reasonable to you.  For example, there is a 96% similarity between the string '001 Chestnut Avenue' and the string '1 Chestnut Avenue' using the Jaro-Winkler algorithm

```
SQL> select utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity( '001 Chestnut Avenue',
  2                                            '1 Chestnut Avenue' )
  3    from dual;

UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY('001CHESTNUTAVENUE','1CHESTNUTAVENUE')
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                      96
```

Obviously, you'd likely need to do some work to identify what weighting to give various fields-- presumably, for example, you'd have a higher threshold to match on the city which is likely to be relatively standardized than on the second line of the address.

Comment: Thanks Justin. You saved me again ! :-)